# Order 4 matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra

Will all matrices of order 4 (cyclic) all have $\pm i$ as eigenvalues?

for example $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ is of order 4 and has $\pm i$ as it's eigenvalues. The reason I ask this is because the order of $\pm i$ is also 4 so is there a natural relation between these two things?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Matrix_representation_of_complex_numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your matrix $A$ has order $4$ then the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $X^4-1$ so the eigenvalues of $A$ will belong to the set $\pm\{1,i\}$. The matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 &-1 &0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has order $4$ and eigenvalues $i,-i$ and $1$ so you can't in general restrict it to just $i$ and $-i$, just to the set $\pm\{1,i\}$.